# Asking a question anonymously

Tags: support

I would like to ask a delicate question on the main site. This question involves professional issues at my department which border the personal level, and involve what you would call academic "politics".

It would be fairly easy for anybody to find out my identity and professional details just by having a look at my profile here on SE. I would therefore be a lot more comfortable asking my question anonymously, so that the people involved cannot be identified (or find out I wrote about this issue on the internet).

I was wondering if it is possible to do so without the need to create another account?

Comment: FYI: [Ability to ask questions anonymously but still get notifications](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136422/255554)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would always assume that whatever you post will get linked back to you. If you do not want people to know, do not post it. As for posting anonymously, you can log out and just post as a guest. There is no need to create a second account. As a guest, you will have limited privileges. After you post, you can log back in.